# What default id should I use such that all the ids in my collection are greater than this id?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I intend to fetch 100 ids at once in a sorted manner.
I `find` the ids greater than `skip` where skip can be set to a default value at the beginning. I need to sort the ids generated in the `find()` and the limit set is 100.
So, my query is:

`db['Organization'].find({"_id":{"$gt":ObjectId(skip)}},{"_id":1}).sort([("_id",1)]).limit(100)`

As of now, I have set skip to str(0). I intend to update it with the last id fetched in the iteration.

The complete endpoint is:

```
@hug.get('/organization/collect_pricing')
def get_organizations():
    start_time = datetime.strptime('2016-11-01', '%Y-%m-%d')
    org_ids = []
    org_pricing_plans = []
    counter = 0
    skip = str(0)
    result_check = True
    pricing_response = []
    ob_toolbox = Toolbox()
    while(result_check is True):
        print(counter)
        try:
            if 
            organizations = db['Organization'].find({"_id":{"$gt":ObjectId(skip)}},{"_id":1}).sort([("_id",1)]).limit(100)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        if organizations.count(True) == 0:
            result_check = False
            continue
        counter += 100
        for org in organizations:
            org_ids.append("Organization$"+org["_id"])
        try:
            pricing_plans = ob_toolbox.bulk_fetch(collection="PricingPlan", identifier="_p_organization", ids=org_ids)
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
        currDict = {}
        for i in range(0, organizations.count(True)):
            currDict["id"] = org_ids[i]
            currDict["expiresAt"] = pricing_plans[i]["expiresAt"]
            currDict["resources"] = pricing_plans[i]["resources"]
            currDict["_created_at"] = pricing_plans[i]["_created_at"]
            org_pricing_plans.append(currDict)
            print(currDict["id"])
            skip = currDict["id"]
        if organizations.count(True) < 100:
            result_check = False
    return (org_pricing_plans)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the default "minimal" value, then null object id is better. It's the same type (ObjectId) and will sort lowest.

```
ObjectId('000000000000000000000000')
```

Alternatively, you could branch when doing a query. Is it first query? If yes, don't include the skip part. If no, use last id from previous results.

Comment: I am getting repetitive ids with this. What could be the issue?

Comment: @hasherBaba What do you mean, repetitive ids?

Comment: Also, going your way, I am getting null.

Comment: I meant the ids which are unique are fetched more than once.

Comment: @hasherBaba I'm 99% confident that it is not because of the null object id value. Something's broken in the rest of your code.

Comment: @hasherBaba: don't have python client, but I tried this in ruby client and mongo shell, works as expected.

Comment: I did not update my variable. Thanks for your input guys, specially @Sergio Tulentsev.

Comment: @hasherBaba: guys? I'm the only one here :)